# Winsock based SMTP Client: stuck on recv() after client data is sent

Tags: c, smtp, winsock, smtpclient

I'm trying to make a simple SMTP client to learn how SMTP actually works, but I'm having some issues that I think have to do with how my code interacts with winsock. All the code that I have done was made thanks to Microsoft's guide on how to [Create a basic Winsock Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/creating-a-basic-winsock-application).

What I've done so far, is try to mimic an SMTP client terminal, in where I can issue the different commands and see what the server answers. When I learn how the exact procedure for different actions are, I will automate the code so that it can easily "send a mail" or "read inbox".

My code as is, lets me receive the server greeting when the connection is opened, and I can try to send a message (like `HELO 1.2.3.4`), but the code gets stuck at `*iResult = recv(*ConnectSocket, out, 200, 0);`.

This is the output I get whe I try to use my code:

```
Bytes received: 111
220 CP6P284CA0098.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 28 Feb 2023
18:17:15 +0000

$> HELO 1.2.3.4
(some time later)
Bytes received: 127
451 4.7.0 Timeout waiting for client input [CP6P284CA0098.BRAP284.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-02-28T18:22:16.228Z 08DB18B4E5C7B417]

$>
```

I dont have full knoweldge on how Winsock works, so maybe its a dumb error. I came to code this with some knoweldge on making SMTP clients on arduino, but that's it.

Here is my code so far:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT "25"

char data[500];

int initWinsock(int *, WSADATA *);
int makeSocket(int *, struct addrinfo *, struct addrinfo **, struct addrinfo **, SOCKET *);
int connSocket(int *, SOCKET *, struct addrinfo *, struct addrinfo *);
int clientReceive(int *, SOCKET *, char *);
int clientSend(int *, char *, SOCKET *);
int closeSocketListener(int *, SOCKET *);
int closeSocket(SOCKET *);

int main() {
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    
    initWinsock(&iResult, &wsaData);

    makeSocket(&iResult, &hints, &result, &ptr, &ConnectSocket);

    connSocket(&iResult, &ConnectSocket, ptr, result);

    while (1){
        char prompt[200] = {0};
        clientReceive(&iResult, &ConnectSocket, data);
        printf("%s\n$> ", data);
        fgets(prompt, sizeof prompt, stdin);
        clientSend(&iResult, prompt, &ConnectSocket);
    }
    

    closeSocketListener(&iResult, &ConnectSocket);

    closeSocket(&ConnectSocket);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int initWinsock(int *iResult, WSADATA *wsaData){
    // Initialize Winsock
    *iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), wsaData);
    if (*iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", *iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int makeSocket(int *iResult, struct addrinfo *hints, struct addrinfo **result, struct addrinfo **ptr, SOCKET *ConnectSocket){
    // Resolve the server address and port
    *iResult = getaddrinfo("52.97.26.134", DEFAULT_PORT, hints, result);
    if (*iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", *iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to the first address returned by
    // the call to getaddrinfo
    *ptr = *result;

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    *ConnectSocket = socket((*ptr)->ai_family, (*ptr)->ai_socktype, (*ptr)->ai_protocol);

    if (*ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(*result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int connSocket(int *iResult, SOCKET *ConnectSocket, struct addrinfo *ptr, struct addrinfo *result){
    // Connect to server.
    *iResult = connect( *ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (*iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(*ConnectSocket);
        *ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    // Should really try the next address returned by getaddrinfo
    // if the connect call failed
    // But for this simple example we just free the resources
    // returned by getaddrinfo and print an error message

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (*ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int clientReceive(int *iResult, SOCKET *ConnectSocket, char *out){
    *iResult = recv(*ConnectSocket, out, 200, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", *iResult);
        return 0;
    } else if (iResult == 0) {
        printf("Connection closed\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 2;
    }

    return -1;
}

int clientSend(int *iResult, char *sendbuf, SOCKET *ConnectSocket){
    *iResult = send(*ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int) strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (*iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(*ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int closeSocketListener(int *iResult, SOCKET *ConnectSocket){
    // shutdown the send half of the connection since no more data will be sent
    *iResult = shutdown(*ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (*iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(*ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int closeSocket(SOCKET *ConnectSocket){
    // cleanup
    closesocket(*ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may be trying to do too much all at once. I'm inferring that you're writing your _first_ client program. And, you're trying to understand `SMTP` at the same time. I might write my own simple server and client programs. Run the server on your local host and get the client to communicate with it. This gets the basics going. There are many examples of this on SO ...

Comment: ...  Also, you're hardwiring an IP address and also trying to talk to `outlook.com`. For production email sites, they may require stuff like SSL/TLS, etc. After doing your sample, you could install a premade SMTP server on your local system and talk to that. You could add (or enable) debug output to the server. Then, debug your client. After you have a client that works correctly to a simple SMTP server, you could try to tackle a "monster" like `outlook.com` or google gmail, hotmail.com, etc.

Comment: IIRC, some sites won't allow `SMTP` unless the client has first connected via `IMAP`--to validate/verify that the client is allowed to connect. So, that's a factor as well.

Comment: There is no `inbox` in SMTP, that's IMAP.  Try to use EHLO instead of HELO.  Have a look at the [upcoming SMTP standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-emailcore-rfc5321bis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

outlook.office365.com server expects that each command ends with CRLF [as required by SMTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321.html#section-2.3.8) and not just LF. This is in contrast to [Postfix](https://www.postfix.org/) and some other servers which are fine with just LF. I have quickly checked that sending `HELO` message with `ncat outlook.office365.com 587` does not work and sending `HELO` message with `ncat --crlf outlook.office365.com 587` works.

fgets stores "\n" (LF) at the end of the buffer, but you need to send "\r\n" (CRLF) after the command.

You can correct it as follows:

```c
int clientSend(int *iResult, char *sendbuf, SOCKET *ConnectSocket){
    int l = strlen(sendbuf);
    if (l == 0) return 0;
    if (sendbuf[l - 1] == '\n' && (l == 1 || sendbuf[l - 2] != '\r')) {
        sendbuf[l - 1] = '\r';
        sendbuf[l++] = '\n';
    }    
    *iResult = send(*ConnectSocket, sendbuf, l, 0);
    ...
}
```

Note that there is always space available in `sendbuf` for replacing LF with CRLF because it is guaranteed to end with `\0` after `fgets()`. We do not need this `\0` because we specify the length explicitly as an argument to `send()` and can overwrite it with LF.

Comment: SMTP standard requires \r\n.  It is not Postfix vs Outlook.

Comment: I added a link to RFC which requires CRLF.